# Saving href to a var and using the value to wrap another element

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, would you be able to help me please?

I have the following HTML:

```
<h4><a href="http://www.google.com">OLD</a></h4>

<div class="test">NEW</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("h4").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).next("a[href]");
    var link = target.href;   
    $(".test").wrap('<a href="' + $(link) + '"></a>');
});
```

The problem is that the new href is returning "Object Object" instead of the target href. If I use `$(link).html()` it returns "undefined".

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dSHH4/51/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.find()` instead of `.next()`

```
$("h4").each(function() {
    //Anchor is child hence use .find()
    //[0] will get you DOM element
    var target = $(this).find("a[href]")[0];

    //Set href
    $(".test").wrap('<a href="' + target.href+ '"></a>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7jfL7umx/)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. And cheers for poiting out the .find() .next() mistake as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can look "into" the `h4` by limiting the selector with `this`

Javascript:

```
$("h4").each(function () {
    var link = $('a[href]', this).attr('href');
    $(".test").wrap('<a href="' + link + '"></a>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dSHH4/52/

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("h4").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).find("a[href]");
    var link = target.attr('href');   
    $(".test").wrap('<a href="' + $(link) + '"></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dSHH4/54/

```
$("h4").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).find("a");
    var link = $(target).attr('href');

    $(".test").wrap('<a href="' + link + '"></a>');
});
```